# CHM html help file does not show contents in Windows 7 although it works fine in XP

Tags: windows, html, windows-7, chm

I have a .chm file it works fine on XP but it does not show its content on Windows 7. The Urdu text can not be shown in Windows 7. ***How can i show its urdu text?*** only urdu images are shown.

I have also decompiled file keytool and get .hhp file. but what can i do with .hhp file to show urdu font after compile again.

I have also tried to show urdu text by unblock with button inside property but it was not there under advance button.
 [chm file download link](http://www.trueislam.info/Downloads/BooksLibrary/BahareShariat/BahareShariat.rar)
website address
[orignal website](http://www.trueislam.info/BooksLibrary/UrduBooks/BahareShariat/index.htm)

As you can see in this picture the contents are not shown.
[image]

Comment: You should not ask us to download a file to see your code. Place the relevant code in your question. I for one will not download the code for fear that there is malware in it.

Comment: there is not malware in it. i have no code for it. you can download from here or can open the side by clicking the orignal webside keyword

Comment: Please show the problem of missing CHM content in the Help Viewer window by a snapshot and add this image by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have your CHM file on a local drive and it's not coming from the web. CHM's from web are blocked for security issues.

After downloading try to right-click on your chm file and select properties. You will see an "Unblock" button. Click on it and you'd see your content.

For further information see:

[CHM Files Not Working](http://www.grainge.org/pages/authoring/chm_mspatch/896358.htm)

[Understanding The Internet File Blocking and Unblocking](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-the-internet-file-blocking-and-unblocking)

Have a look at all answers in following threads (SuperUser):

[How to unblock chm files - unblock button is missing](https://superuser.com/questions/503812/how-to-unblock-chm-files-unblock-button-is-missing)

[How to unblock ...](https://superuser.com/questions/503812/how-to-unblock-chm-files-unblock-button-is-missing) .

Please read all answers and try for your needs.

Comment: CHM file is already in local drive. i have already checked it after transferring the drive C,D and E drive. but same problem no unblock button is shown even after transfering

Comment: @Kashif - I added some links for further information (delayed update because of a trip to Norway).